# VS code: JDK 13 not working in WSL ubuntu

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, java-home

For some reason whenever I try running VS code within the WSL it says that "The JAVA_HOME environment variable (/mnt/c/Program Files/jdk-13.0.1) does not point to a JDK."

When I simply run VS code normally(not in WSL) it works fine and there are no issues.

If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: have you set your `java.home` correctly in your workspace setting?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT I originally set java.home to the same location as the JAVA_HOME but for some reason java.home messes up both the WSL and regular VS codes. So I just took it out so it defaults to looking at the JAVA_HOME

Comment: Try to append the `/bin` folder in that Java home environment variable.

Comment: @Biswapriyo I tried that and get the same error

Comment: so apparently I fixed it by removing the JAVA_HOME entirely and it automatically found a jdk in my /usr/lib/jvm from my WSL ubuntu terminal. I have no idea where this came from though, and I also don't understand how when I type 'ls -a' that the usr folder dosen't come up when I'm in my root directory in my WSL.