# Configuring Java Extension Pack in Remote WSL on VSCode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58739440/vs-code-jdk-13-not-working-in-wsl-ubuntu). I am trying to work with Java in Remote-WSL using VSCode. According to VSCode [guidelines](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl), I should install the Java Extension Pack on WSL. However, when I try to install it I get the following error:

```
The java.home variable defined in Visual Studio Code settings points to a missing or inaccessible folder (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1)
```

This is what the Java Extension pack shows when I install it on WSL.

[image]

I have been able to resolve this issue if I change the path in `java.home` to be same as `JAVA_HOME` in `settings.json`. However, I need to toggle the path back to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1` manually when working on my local machine and not on Remote-WSL.

Is there a better way to make it work?

PS: I've no clue why it says that `JDK_HOME` is empty. If I `echo $JDK_HOME` inside WSL, it shows the path same as `JAVA_HOME`.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to develop Java in WSL, you need to install JDK in WSL. Now from the way you frame your questions I would assume you have done that (it needs to be installed as a Linux program, so if your `JAVA_HOME` starts with anything like `/mnt/c` then you don't actually have it on WSL).

> I have been able to resolve this issue if I change the path in java.home to be same as JAVA_HOME in settings.json. However, I need to toggle the path back to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1 manually when working on my local machine and not on Remote-WSL.

The problem you mentioned here is relatively simple to solve. All you need to do is to have a WSL specific settings for `java.home`, and have the normal setting (i.e. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1`) remain in your normal VS Code settings. To access WSL specific settings, use `CTRL+SHIFT+P` then type "Open Remote Settings".[image]

Answer (score 1):

Copied answer to *one* possible problem/solution from the **Q** above for visibility here:

> I have been able to resolve this issue if I change the path in `java.home` to be same as `JAVA_HOME` in `settings.json`. However, I need to toggle the path back to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1` manually when working on my local machine and not on Remote-WSL.

Before installing the *Java Extension Pack* on the WSL side of things you should have something similar to this (so, yeah --> Click that button!):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i solved my problem running this comand on WSL

> sudo apt install default-jdk

Answer (score -1):

I think you should install JDK in WSL.